# Giving a speech to or giving a speech for?

Tags: grammar

I just read this tweet: 
“Timothee Chalamet gives a HELL OF A SPEECH for @JOSH_BENNY at #NBR for Best Original Screenplay”

I am wondering if it’s correct to write “gives a speech for” I tough it should be “gives a speech to”. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, it means just that. The guy was speaking to praise another at an event.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these sentences would be valid, and while technically they have different meanings, they will be interpreted very similarly by most English speakers. You are correct that "(speaker) gives a speech to (audience)" is the most direct way of expressing that the speaker speaks, with the intent that he be heard by the audience.

The phrasing "(speaker) gives a speech for (beneficiary)" has a different meaning; here, instead of describing the subject of the speech (the people intended to here it), we are giving the motivation of the speech (why is he speaking?). Often, the primary purpose of a speech is to entertain, motivate, inform, or otherwise affect the audience. In this case, the two sentences have essentially the same meaning. This phrasing could also be used in other circumstances, however; for example, one might give a speech "for the environment" to convince people not to pollute the oceans; in this case, the audience is not the beneficiary, and it would be inaccurate to say the speech was given "to the environment." In practice, it can usually be assumed that the audience is the beneficiary unless context suggests otherwise.

Regarding the example you cited, the reason the more ambiguous wording was chosen was likely (though maybe not consciously) to add an emotional impact to the tweet; saying someone did something "for someone", that they provided service, inclines the audience to think positively of the person described. As such, people who are adept at (or reliant on) influencing others' opinions will often use emotionally charged language like this in their writing or speech.